# Phalcon 3.0 to Phalcon 2.0 compatibilty

Tags: php, compatibility, phalcon, incompatibility, phalcon-routing

I had created a barebone Phalcon 3.0 project with Devtools 3.0, it worked fine on my machine
Then I uploaded to my web host service, and it reproduced error message:
`Argument 1 passed to Phalcon\Di\Injectable::setDI() must implement interface Phalcon\DiInterface, instance of Wegawe\Modules\Frontend\Module given in /home/wewe/web/app/modules/frontend/Module.php on line 41`

Then I realized that my web host service uses Phalcon 2.0 instead of Phalcon 3.0

Are there any tricks to solve this? Sorry for my bad english. :D

Here's my app/bootstrap_web.php:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Application;

error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
define('APP_PATH', BASE_PATH . '/app');

try {

    /**
     * The FactoryDefault Dependency Injector automatically registers the services that
     * provide a full stack framework. These default services can be overidden with custom ones.
     */
    $di = new FactoryDefault();

    /**
     * Include general services
     */
    require APP_PATH . '/config/services.php';

    /**
     * Include web environment specific services
     */
    require APP_PATH . '/config/services_web.php';

    /**
     * Get config service for use in inline setup below
     */
    $config = $di->getConfig();

    /**
     * Include Autoloader
     */
    include APP_PATH . '/config/loader.php';

    /**
     * Handle the request
     */
    $application = new Application($di);

    /**
     * Register application modules
     */
    $application->registerModules([
        'frontend' => ['className' => 'Wegawe\Modules\Frontend\Module'],
    ]);

    /**
     * Include routes
     */
    require APP_PATH . '/config/routes.php';

    echo $application->handle()->getContent();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
    echo '<pre>' . $e->getTraceAsString() . '</pre>';
}
```

app/modules/frontend/Module.php:

```
<?php
namespace Wegawe\Modules\Frontend;

use Phalcon\DiInterface;
use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Php as PhpEngine;
use Phalcon\Mvc\ModuleDefinitionInterface;

class Module implements ModuleDefinitionInterface
{
    /**
     * Registers an autoloader related to the module
     *
     * @param DiInterface $di
     */
    public function registerAutoloaders(DiInterface $di = null)
    {
        $loader = new Loader();

        $loader->registerNamespaces([
            'Wegawe\Modules\Frontend\Controllers' => __DIR__ . '/controllers/',
            'Wegawe\Modules\Frontend\Models' => __DIR__ . '/models/',
        ]);

        $loader->register();
    }

    /**
     * Registers services related to the module
     *
     * @param DiInterface $di
     */
    public function registerServices(DiInterface $di)
    {
        /**
         * Setting up the view component
         */
        $di->set('view', function () {
            $view = new View();
            $view->setDI($this);
            $view->setViewsDir(__DIR__ . '/views/');

            $view->registerEngines([
                '.volt'  => 'voltShared',
                '.phtml' => PhpEngine::class
            ]);

            return $view;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Update your web server or change your code :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
$view->setDI($this);
```

to

```
$view->setDI($di);
```